# EF Core 2 w/ UsingSqlServer DB not created

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am getting into Core 2 and in my initial dev I had been using the in memory db option for Entity Framework and things ran smooth. 
Getting ready to deploy, I switched over to UseSqlServer option and tried to add migrations to create my db, running

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate
```

errors out, stating the connection string is null.

```
    PM> Add-Migration InitialCreate
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: connectionString
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 sqlServerOptionsAction)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer[TContext](DbContextOptionsBuilder`1 optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 sqlServerOptionsAction)
   at SmartMiner.API.DesignTimeDbContextFactory.CreateDbContext(String[] args) in C:\code\SmartMiner\SmartMiner copy\SmartMiner.API\DesignTimeDbContextFactory.cs:line 19
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContextFromFactory(Type factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<FindContextTypes>b__3()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: connectionString
```

When launching in debug I can see that when StartUp.cs calls

```
services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationContext>(options => {             options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DebugContext"));
            });
```

using ImmediateWindow I can confirm that `Configuration.GetConnectionString("DebugContext")`

does return the stated connection string

the connection string being

```
    {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ProdContext": "Data Source=tcp:azuredb.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=MYDB;User Id=xxx@azuredb.database.windows.net;Password=xxxx;",
    "DebugContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=DebugDb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Nor when I run the project and do an operation such as registering a new user, which is supposed (or used to) trigger the full creation of the db if it does not exist.

I have had no issues in the days of dotnet 4.5 and web.config... but am feeling a little lost and dumbfounded here not even being able to create my db...

Comment: Your actual question is not clear. `DB not created` or `Migrations not created`?

Comment: @Zeeshan I have update my question to reflect the fact that both using migration and trying to initiate the db by running project and doing some operation like registering a new user do not yield a created db

Answer (score 1):

You are one step away. `Add-Migration InitialCreate` doesn't actually creates database. It only creates migrations. After migrations has been created, you need to apply the created migrations logic, in order to have the physical effect of it. Run following command in order to apply the created migrations.

> **Update-Database**

This will apply the pending migrations, hence generating the database/tables etc.
Please refer to [Migrations - EF Core with ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/) docs for detailed understanding

Comment: Thanks, but the underlying problem here is that EF can not retrieve the connection string. I can confirm that in ConfigureServices in Startup.cs I can get the connection string using Configuration.GetConnectionString but the initial create of the migration folder etc does not happen.

Comment: Please show more of `.json` file. I'll need to look at file structure above and below the `"ConnectionStrings": {...`

Comment: I have updated my question with the full appsettings.json content

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework Migration seems to be looking for a specifically named connection string. i.e "DefaultConnection".
I added the following line to my appsettings.json and it works.

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=DebugDb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
```